# Android ListView not showing on real device but on emulator does

Tags: android, json, listview, emulation, device

I'm having a weird problem regarding the simple `ListView`.
On my emulator everything is allright and the data is loaded correctly from JSON API, the data also loads on my device.
The problem is that on my emulator, the `listview` is populated but on my real device, not, even if there is data from JSON, why ?

```
    private void addItemsToListView(JSONObject message) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = message.getJSONArray("android");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String imagePath = c.getString("path");
            try {
                myImages.add(new ImagesModel(i, imagePath, R.drawable.mtr));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or anything.

Comment: No, just the title and an empty screen [link](https://static.daniweb.com/attachments/2/01ed211f4a04fbb58e8322ba1b9d761d.jpg) -> this is the emulator and [link](https://www.daniweb.com/attachments/small/2/32b4c309af05c969d0b843c69cb60b24.jpg) -> this is my device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem, I've changed the layout from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout and it is all working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/view_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="@integer/abc_config_activityShortDur"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/btnUploadedActivity"
    android:id="@+id/imagesListViewTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imagesListView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imagesListViewTitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imagesListViewTitle"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```