# In emulator my app running fine but not in real device

Tags: android

I have ListView in my app, it shows up in emulator but when I tried in real device it did not...it post to server and get json format in return and show it in listview...

I have two layouts, first hasilpencarian_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorGray">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_circled_back"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/waktu"
            android:text="waktu"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/header2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.rey.material.widget.EditText
            android:id="@+id/kotaasalLengkap"
            android:text="Dari"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/carmoving"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:editable="false"
            app:et_dividerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:et_dividerHeight="2dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carmoving"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_taxi"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <com.rey.material.widget.EditText
            android:id="@+id/kotatujuanLengkap"
            android:text="Ke"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/carmoving"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:editable="false"
            app:et_dividerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:et_dividerHeight="2dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/strip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/strip_repeat"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"/>

    <solar.blaz.date.week.WeekDatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_below="@+id/strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/date_picker_day_textcolor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:wdp_labelTextSize="12sp"
        app:wdp_labelPadding="5dp"
        app:wdp_dayBackground="@drawable/date_picker_day_bg"
        app:wdp_firstDayOfWeek="monday"
        app:wdp_labelTextColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listtaxi"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

second, list_row_taxi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Nama Taxi / mitra -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/namataxi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/namataxi"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <!-- icon jam -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_waktu"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_action_query_builder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/namataxi"/>

    <!-- waktu -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/waktu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/namataxi"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_waktu"
        android:textSize="@dimen/waktu"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteFade" />


    <!-- Jumlah kursi yang teredia -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kursi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/waktu"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/kursi"
        android:textSize="@dimen/kursi" />

    <!-- Tarif -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tarif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorYellowDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/tarif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my code to post parameters to server:

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                dialog.dismiss();

                try{
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("daftar_taxi");

                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        Taxi taxi = new Taxi();
                        taxi.setNamataxi(c.getString("mitra_nama"));
                        taxi.setThumbnailUrl(c.getString("image"));
                        taxi.setWaktu(c.getString("wkt_berangkat") + " - " + c.getString("wkt_sampai"));
                        taxi.setKursi("Kursi yang tersedia: " + c.getInt("jml_kursi"));
                        taxi.setTarif(c.getInt("tarif"));
                        taxiList.add(taxi);
                        Log.d(TAG, taxiList.toString());
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("dari", textkodeasal_btn);
                params.put("ke", textkodetujuan_btn);
                params.put("jml_penumpang", jml_penumpang);

                Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
```

Comment: have you tried adding dummy lists only for testing purpose ?

Comment: yes, I have...and its fine

Comment: Then you are saying dummy list is showing in both. But the list you had to grab from server is not showing in real device is it?

Comment: yes, as you say....any suggestion

Comment: First make sure you have internet connection as well as required permissions too. Then debug that in real device. Log the received json data. Then tell what happens ? I will be here.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Android ListView not showing on real device but on emulator does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938466/android-listview-not-showing-on-real-device-but-on-emulator-does)

You can Check if the problem is same with your code. Otherwise you can check for this solution too. [Android app working on emulator but not on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248152/android-app-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device)

Comment: @meeftah what is the URL?

Comment: @meeftah this is the error. Got it. Change it to localhost url for android device. chexk edit for the clarification.

Comment: my code works fine in emulator, but not in the device

Comment: @meeftah As i suggested in my edit that Emulator works with IPAddress of the system so you used the URL `192.241.191.104/androidapp/showtaxi.php` But if you want to work with Real Device you need to provide URL like this: `localhost/androidapp/showtaxi.php`.

Comment: @meeftah I tested your webservice with restClient i am getting null array.

Comment: it because when you click it without proper post you will get an error...try it with POSTMAN with post dari=PTK, ke=SGU, jml_penumpang=1 and you will get the result

Comment: @meeftah Still same. Null array.

Comment: @meeftah check for the image i just uploaded in my answer, you will see a null array.

Comment: my bad, change ke=SGU to ke=SAG

Comment: @meeftah Ok Got it. Change your root `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` in `first hasilpencarian_layour.xml`, then check it please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107827/discussion-between-meeftah-and-android-geek).